# SQL Server weirdest error ever

Tags: c#, sql-server

The C# code:

```
SqlConnection c;

string str = "Data Source =(LocalDB)\\MSSQLLocalDB;";
str += "AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\\DinoData.mdf;";
str += "Integrated Security= True";

c = new SqlConnection(str);

if (Session["Connect"] != null)
{
    if ((bool)Session["Connect"])
    {
        logdiv.Visible = false;
        Usernamec.InnerHtml = (string)Session["CurentUserid"];
        Connected.Visible = true;

        SqlCommand exp = new SqlCommand("SELECT xp FROM[User] Where Username = @username", c);
        exp.Parameters.AddWithValue("@username", (string)Session["CurentUserid"]);

        c.Open();
        Session["exp"] = exp.ExecuteReader();
        c.Close();

        int b = (int)Session["exp"] / 2;
        string a = b + "px";
        xp.Style.Add("width", ((string)Session["exp"])+"%");
    }
    else
    {
        Connected.Visible = false;
        logdiv.Visible = true;
    }
}
```

The error:

> An exception of type 'System.InvalidCastException' occurred in
>   App_Web_ump4h2pq.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: Specified cast is not valid.

Comment: Man, if this is your "weirdest error ever", I'll promise you, there are _way_ more errors for you to discover.

Comment: You are putting a DataReader into your session and the casting it to an integer a few lines later. Then after another few lines you cast it to a string...

Comment: This is sort of an unrelated question, but is there a reason you are storing all of this in `Session` instead of local variables?

Comment: [Can we stop using AddWithValue() already](http://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/)

Answer (score 2):

```
 SqlConnection c;
        string str = "Data Source =(LocalDB)\\MSSQLLocalDB;";
        str += "AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\\DinoData.mdf;";
        str += "Integrated Security= True";
        c = new SqlConnection(str);
        if (Session["Conect"] != null)
        {
            if ((bool)Session["Conect"])
            {
                logdiv.Visible = false;
                Usernamec.InnerHtml = (string)Session["CurentUserid"];
                Connected.Visible = true;
                SqlCommand exp = new SqlCommand("SELECT xp FROM[User] Where Username = @username", c);
                exp.Parameters.AddWithValue("@username", (string)Session["CurentUserid"]);
                c.Open();
                Session["exp"] = exp.ExecuteScalar();
                c.Close();
                int b = (int)Session["exp"] / 2;
                string a = b + "%";
                xp.Style.Add("width", a);
            }
            else
            {
                Connected.Visible = false;
                logdiv.Visible = true;
            }
```

fixed :)

Comment: Deleted my answer, this would actually be better, just use `ExecuteScalar` instead of extracting a single value from a data set.